# not seeing a sequelize model property that is required after seeding database

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

**UPDATE**

someone below suggested adding in a model id for shoutouts and I'm no longer getting the error, but now nothing is being saved to my database?
adding in the new information below:

I have a one to many relationship between users and shoutouts. Both models have email property,
I am trying to use a magic method to setup the shoutout. When I use user.createShoutout()
I can generate the shoutout, but the email property doesn't show up in the database.

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
const db = require('../db')

const Shoutout = db.define('shoutout', {
//NEW
  id: {
    allowNull: false,
    autoIncrement: true,
    primaryKey: true,
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER
  }, //OLD
  name: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    validate: {
      notEmpty: true
    },
    email: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      unique: true,
      allowNull: false
    }
  },
  message: {
    type: Sequelize.TEXT,
    allowNull: false
  },
  from: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING
  }
})

module.exports = Shoutout
```

associations:

```
User.hasMany(Shoutouts)
Shoutouts.belongsTo(User)

User.hasMany(Emails)
Emails.belongsTo(User)
```

when I use user.AddShoutout()
as follows:

```
   let paramsObj = {     
        name: addEmail.firstName,
        email:addEmail.email,
        message: 'test msg',
        userId: 3
}
//NEW
let id = 1;
    const addInfo = await userThree.addShoutout(id,paramsObj)
```

//NEW

not getting the object error anymore, in fact not seeing any errors. But when I look in my shoutouts table nothing is getting added.

when I console.log addInfo
The user who tried to create the shoutout gets returned?

I need help with trying to get this user model magic method to generate a new shoutout!

Thanks for reading this, and any advice!

Comment: show code where you add Shoutout

Comment: In the sack of lacking a primary in the shoutout model, Sequelize generates an Id to this model. By the way, to handle relations you should define the target key properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your email field is nested within name field

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
const db = require('../db')

const Shoutout = db.define('shoutout', {

  id: {
    allowNull: false,
    autoIncrement: true,
    primaryKey: true,
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER
  }, //OLD
  name: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    validate: {
      notEmpty: true
    },
    email: { # <----------------------------- nested too deep
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      unique: true,
      allowNull: false
    }
  },
  message: {
    type: Sequelize.TEXT,
    allowNull: false
  },
  from: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING
  }
})

module.exports = Shoutout
```